# How to track java Object during garbage collection

Tags: object, garbage-collection, jvm

We recently encountered the problem of too frequent fullgc, which made us very confused. It was observed that a large number of objects lived through younggc 15 times while processing the request, and can be collected during fullgc.
The question is how can we find these objects that can be recycled by fullgc but not by younggc? We need to use this as a point to locate the corresponding business code. I checked many documents and found no way to track these objects.
this is observed using jstat -gcold and print every second.

[jstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFCCl.jpg)

Comment: When these objects are promoted to the old generation, it usually implies that they still are reachable and a full gc would not collect them. So a larger young generation would help. If, however, they are unreachable as you seem to assume, tracking them wouldn’t help, as being unreachable implies that there is no trace. And “a large number of objects” and “tracking” don’t go well together anyway…

Comment: Hi @Holger  , actually We suppose that these objects that cannot be recycled by younggc are related to cache. There may be some references held by objects in the cache, which make them reachable during younggc. and The cache has been deleted during or before fullgc, making these references unreachable and so recyclable. Therefore, I want to find these references and consider the optimization approach.But how? seems no way to track them.

Comment: When there’s a cache holding references, you should be able to query the cache shouldn’t you? Besides that, the answer seems to lead towards making a heap dump at the right time and analyze it.